# Prove L’Hôspital’s rule without the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Does there exist a proof for L’Hôspital’s rule without relying on the mean value theorem?

Or do all proofs essentially rely on MVT?

Comment: I believe it is a classical consequence of the cauchy mean value theorem. You'd probably be hard pressed to find a proof that doesn't rely on the MVT.

Comment: Why do you ask? Without knowing your motivation for asking the question, it's hard to formulate a useful answer.

Comment: This is wan excellent question, +1! I hope you don’t mind my edit $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Rob I can very well understand your statement. However, my question is merely because an instructor of mine claimed that it couldn't be proved without MVT and I wanted to confirm that/perhaps understand why that would be the case. His motivation of telling us that is that at first, l'Hospital is merely a 1D statement (it's a Complex Analysis class). While we can somewhat modify the statement, I was interested in whether it really is true that MVT is necessary to prove the theorem.

Comment: Thanks for giving the context. I've voted to reopen your question.

Comment: I've been trying to proof this with Nonstandard-Analysis without MVT as well, but to no avail. Let's hope somebody can lift the secret

Answer (score 5):

There is a special case of L'Hôpital’s theorem. We assume that $f(c) = g(c) = 0$, $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $c$, and have continuous derivatives. Then

$$\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x+c) - f(c)}{g(x+c) - g(c)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{f(x+c) - f(c)}{x}}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x+c) - g(c)}{x}} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \color{blue}{\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}}$$.

Comment: Am I overlooking somethig? Where do you actually use "have continuous derivatives"?

Comment: When I implicitly assume that $f'(c)/g'(c) = \lim_{x \to c} f'(x)/g'(x)$

Comment: So you are also assuming that $g'(c) \neq 0$. I don't see how this really answers the question which is about the general case, not this special case.

Comment: It is a partial answer. This site is chock full of partial answers. Also, the question never specifically said the "general case."

Comment: Well, you should make your assumptions clear at the outset. Basically your "special case" is just the case where $g'(c)\ne 0$ and we approximate both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by their tangent lines. $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(c)(x-c)+ o(x-c)}{g'(c)(x-c)+o(x-c)} \to \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}.$$ This is a more natural way to give the exposition in this special case.

Comment: I simply forgot to put a single assumption. It's a tangent line approximation of course: that's what I was thinking, so I made it into an answer.

Comment: This is by no means a special case of l'Hôpital. It is just applying the definition of derivative and standard theorems on limits.

Comment: Take a look, @egreg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Special_case

You want to edit the wikipedia page to put "Not special case?" That's like saying "Lhopital's isn't a theorem. It's just applying the Cauchy MVT and standard theorems on limits."

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah I stand by my opinion (and I won't change the silly part of that page, as it's useless, because someone else would revert the change like it happened to me, from a guy who admitted later to knowing very little about the subject). That's *at most* motivation for the very important l'Hôpital's theorem, whose proof is definitely not just applying the MVT. Continuity of the derivatives plays no role in the theorem.

Comment: So, when someone asks how to prove l'Hôpital's without Cauchy MVT and you remark you can prove a special case without it it's just invalid?

Comment: While this special case (of course you can debate whether it really is a special case) doesn't explicitly answer my question, I still believe that it's a valuable answer. That's how math works, doesn't it? Small contributions always help, even contributions that maybe stray from the original topic. Such answers can very well inspire people - so thank you.

Comment: In your third equation, isn't it $$\frac{\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{f(x+c) - f(c)}{x}}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x+c) - g(c)}{x}} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$instead of $$\frac{\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{f(x+c) - f(c)}{c}}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x+c) - g(c)}{c}} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$?

Comment: Correct, thanks for catching that!

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah: what about proving that $\lim f(x)/g(x)=f^{(k)}(x)/g^{(k)}(x)$ where $k$ is the smallest order such that the denominator is nonzero ?

Comment: This *is* a special case, and might be called "the calculus student's L'hopital's rule", in the sense that it's all that's needed to address hundreds of things of the form $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$, which is most of what arises in calc courses. There's a natural corollary that allows one to remove the $f(c) = g(c) = 0$ condition, by letting $F(x) = f(x) - f(c), G(x) = g(x) - g(c)$, and then applying your theorem to $F$ and $G$. Now the calc student is even more empowered. :)

Comment: @RobArthan This can be used to prove l'hopitals rule for other indeterminate forms since all indeterminate forms can be written in the form $0/0$ see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms)